# The Fubini-Study metric and its associated form.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Assume $ds^2$ is Fubini-Study metric, and $\omega = -\frac{1}{2}Im \{ds^2\}$ is its associated form.

Let $V_n = \int_{\mathbb{C}P^n} \omega^n / n!$ the volume of $\mathbb{C}P^n$.

Let $V \subset \mathbb{C}P^n$ be a complex closed submanifold, with $\deg V = d , \ \dim_{\mathbb{C}} V = m$.

I want to show that the form $d\cdot \frac{v_m m!}{v_n n!} \omega^{n-m}=W$, satisfies:

$\int_M \psi \wedge W = \int_V \psi$, for $\psi$ which is a closed form of degree $2m$.

Any references or answers for this question?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is Poincare duality for complex projective space. It is covered in all standard texts (Griffith-Harris, Bott-Tu).